# How to the average number of records per hour in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I calculate the average number of records per hour in PostgreSQL?
I have a user column in my table and a task column (task execution time) in the format 2021-04-01 00: 00: 00.249000,
Need to calculate:
How many tasks does the user per hour
How many hours a day he works (If at least one task is completed at a certain hour, then the user was working at that hour).
In the time period between February and March

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Table looks like this: First column - user id, next column date timestamp. Date means completion date.
I need to get from this
1) how many tasks an hour on average he completed? 



271322,2021-03-01 18:50:11.500977
298037,2021-03-01 18:50:14.258915
3933,2021-03-01 18:50:15.151590
298039,2021-03-01 18:50:15.771959
221485,2021-03-01 18:50:15.253338
271322,2021-03-01 18:50:17.983407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select userid, count(distinct date_trunc('hour', datetime)) as hours worked,
       count(*) * 1.0 / count(distinct date_trunc('hour', datetime)) as avg_tasks_per_hour
from t
where datetime >= '2021-02-01' and datetime < '2021-04-01'
group by userid;
```